# Using vim/gvim as editor for Thunderbird

Tags: vim, gvim, thunderbird

Is there a way to use vim/gvim as an editor for thunderbird?  There was an add-on for it but it is now very out of date.

Comment: Do you know [*Muttator*](http://vimperator.org/muttator)?  This Vimperator-like plugin might be interesting to the VIM fan using Thunderbird `:)` [This issue makes it seem to me like there was *external editor support* in `muttator` (news to me)](http://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/detail?id=554)

Comment: @sr_: Yes, I am using that but the editor is still the one that thunderbird uses internally which I do not like.

Comment: Already answered on [AU](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38077/using-gvim-as-editor-for-thunderbird), cannot say if still valid.

Comment: @enzotib: Sadly, it does not work any longer.  I could not get it to actually open a message to reply.  It does open an empty gvim window but that's of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the [Teledactyl](http://5digits.org/teledactyl) add-on for Thunderbird from *5digits.org*.  They produce a [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl) add-on for firefox which works nicely for controls, although text boxes are admittedly un-vim-ish.

Feature-list says it supports external editors, so gvim could be in your future.